# Instragram Embed Not Working on React app

Tags: reactjs, instagram

I got pretty far with this considering the errors that Web Pack was causing but I hit a snag. Here's my code. I've XXX-ed out the secret, and token but I retrieved them from my facebook app that i created via the developer console.

```
  function InstagramFeed() {

  const APP_ID = 639657380440168;
  const APP_SECRET = "xxxx"
  const CLIENT_TOKEN = "xxx"

  return (
    <div>
      <InstagramEmbed
        url='https://instagram.com/myprofile'
        clientAccessToken={APP_ID | CLIENT_TOKEN}
        maxWidth={320}
        hideCaption={false}
        containerTagName='div'
        protocol=''
        injectScript
        onLoading={() => { }}
        onSuccess={() => { }}
        onAfterRender={() => { }}
        onFailure={() => { }}
      />

    </div>
  )
export default InstagramFeed
```

The error I am getting is a 401 https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/instagram_oembed/?url=https%3A%2F%2Finstagram.com%2Fshanstasticeric&hidecaption=false&omitscript=true&fields=html&maxwidth=320

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks